# Is there any way to create Custom REST API for custom database tables in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, crud

I am creating an android application and I am using wordpress to create website for the same.
I need an a REST API to handle data of the app and users.

I need to store various kinds of data for which I need a seperate database on the same server, which will include centralized of the app and the website.
Why I need to do this? Because I don't know how to create a REST api with any other PHP framework. 
And I don't want to use firebase as I need to store data in a Structured Database like MySQL.

Is there any way to write custom controllers for CRUD operations for a separte database in wordpress?
Or if not a separate database then is there any way to use the API for custom tables in the same database as of wordpress?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221808/how-would-i-add-custom-tables-endpoints-to-the-wp-rest-api

Comment: This could possibly be of your help:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263968/180686

Comment: I had already read the answer you guys provided the link to. But I am still looking if what I want is possible or not with a separate database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can extend the WP REST API pretty much any way you want. You can add any routes you'd like with the [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) function.

For example I have a couple of custom post types that rely on information from other relational databases and tables.

```
foreach( $ext_post_types as $post_type ){
    $post_type = pluralize($post_type);

    register_rest_route( 'ext/v1', "/{$post_type}/(?P<ID>\d+)", array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => "extended_api_endpoint_{$post_type}"
    ) );
}
```

Inside each callback function, I handle all the data I need from the other tables, the post type, etc

```
function extended_api_endpoint_props( $data ){
    $external_data = get_external_relational_data( absint($data['ID']) );

    if( empty( $external_data ) ){
        return null;
    }

    $return = array();
    foreach( $external_data as $data_id ){
        $return[] = generate_json_data( $data_id );
    }

    return $return;
}
```

This lets me pull all the information I want (the `get_external_relational_data()` function is a function that uses the [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) class to pull in everything I want from the custom tables, and then I have another custom function that returns it in a WP REST API valid JSON format `generate_json_data()`, then return the data.

This lets me access https://[MYSITE].com/wp-json/ext/v1/props/12345 to get all of my custom database information while still being integrated into the WP REST API natively.

Comment: Could you please provide any resource where I can learn creating sunch an API to work with other RDBs, as I already mentioned I don't know how to create API with PHP, I have only knowledge how to customise the existing Wordpress API to a small extent.

Is there any tutorial article or video in your knowledge which shows how to do this.
And the data I want to store in separte database are only values, I don't want to create any custom post for that.

Comment: I don't know any tutorials/videos offhand, I apologize. But you don't *need* to create a custom post type, that's just my particular implementation. Just use the `register_rest_route` function, and create a callback function for it. Inside that callback function is where you'll pull in the data however you want and however you're comfortable, it just needs to return a JSON string.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it. So I register the route by "register_rest_route" function and in the callback function I only need to write the required SQL queries and the work will be done, right?

Comment: Yup, that's basically it - just make sure to return the SQL in JSON format!